# Java out of memory when trying to parse a XML file

Tags: java, xml

I have a fairly large XML file (~280 MB) and each row in the XML file has many attributes, I want to extract 3 attributes from it and store it somewhere. But I ran out of memory when I do that. My code looks like this:

```
File xmlFile = new File(xml);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
} catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");
for (int index = 0; index < nList.getLength(); index++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(index);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        System.out.print("F1 : " + 
            nNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("F1").getTextContent());
        System.out.print(" F2: " + 
            nNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("F2").getTextContent());
        System.out.println(" F3: " + 
            nNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("F3").getTextContent());
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl.getNodeObject(DeferredDocumentImpl.java:974)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl.synchronizeData(DeferredElementImpl.java:121)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementImpl.getTagName(ElementImpl.java:314)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.nextMatchingElementAfter(DeepNodeListImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.item(DeepNodeListImpl.java:146)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl.getLength(DeepNodeListImpl.java:117)
    at Parser.parsePosts(Parser.java:55)
    at Parser.main(Parser.java:72)
```

How do I change it to prevent going over too much space?

EDIT:
Wrote a new parser using SAX, seems to get the job done. The code is:

```
try {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                System.out.print(attributes.getValue("F1") + " ");
                System.out.print(attributes.getValue("F2") + " ");
                System.out.println(attributes.getValue("F3"));
            }
        };

        saxParser.parse("file.xml", handler);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have to use the DOM API? This *will* load the entire file into memory at once, there's no way around it. But you could use something like SAX instead, which won't.

Comment: I don't have to use it. I just Googled around and found DOM. I'm willing to use anything that is the most efficient.

Comment: Look up SAX, it might fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve your problem. You can either increase the maximum memory on your application or use sax to parse your xml file.

Comment: worked perfectly, guess if your input file is, ex: 1.8GB then using a DOM parser for it will require like 5GB+ whoa! Worked swell with a SAX one though.

Answer (score 1):

Try the parameter `-Xmx<size>` when you run to increase the size of your heap.

E.g., `java -Xmx500m <filename>`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to increase the memory limits of your Java VM: Set -Xmx=2048 or some other large enough value like that.